# Authenticate LDAP + ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, ldap

I'm trying to integrate `LDAP` + `ZF2` through `\ZEND\Ldap\Ldap`, but this is not working...

This is my error:

```
    if (!extension_loaded('ldap')) {
        throw new Exception\LdapException(null, 'LDAP extension not loaded', Exception\LdapException::LDAP_X_EXTENSION_NOT_LOADED);
    }
```

The main problem is the `php_ldap.dll` is loaded in my server, I checked repeatedly the `php.ini`. Also, I try this connection through the `WAMP` Server (`localhost`), but happen same problem.

How can I solve this error? Do I need others `dll`s?

Comment: Is LDAP extension really loaded? How did you test that?

Comment: @foozy I downloaded the dll (php_ldap.dll) again then replace it in php/ext. But I dont' know what was the error first dll.But I can't identify the error of first dll. thanks for help

Comment: Is ldap extension info exists in phpinfo() output?